# Mongodb, search for text and geolocation in different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections: business, sevice, employee.

I need search by service (without fulltext), by employee and by the geolocation of each business, and should show only business.

```
var BusinessSchema = new Schema({   
        business_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique:true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
        },      
        description:{
            type: String
        },
        location:{
            country:{
                type:String,
            },
            city:{
                type:String
            },
            coord:[Number]
        }       
        services:[{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Service'
        }]
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    });


var ServiceSchema = new Schema({
        business:{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Business'
        },      
        category:{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
            index:true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            index:true
        },
        employee: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }], 
        {
        timestamps: true
    });

var UserSchema = new Schema({
        birthday:Date,

        first_name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        last_name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
            required: true
        },
        password:{
            type: String
        },
        {
        timestamps: true
    });
```

What changes should i make collections to optimize the query?

```
Service.distinct('business',filter_services)
        .exec(function (err, business) {
            if (err) {
                return cb({ status: 400, message: err }, null);
            } else {
                if(business.length > 0){
                    var filter_business = [{is_active:true},{is_approved:true}]
                    filter_business.push({_id:{$in:business}})
                    filter_business.push({location.coord:input_coord}})
                    filter_business = {$and:filter_business}

                    Business.find(filter_business)
                    .select('name services')
                    .exec(function (err,result){
                        if(err){
                            return cb({ status: 400, message: err }, null);
                        }
                        else{
                            if(result.length > 0){
                                var total = result.length;

                            }
                            return cb(null, result);
                        }
                    })
                }
                // si no hay business en el primer query, se retorna [].
                else{
                    return cb(null, business);
                }

            }            
        });
```

Could geo filter by text and at the same time to get closer to a point?

For now, i am not using the Employee collection, but, if i would search by business name, employee name and service name simultaneously, what changes should make.

Comment: Your question is not much clear. What is your current query that you want to optimise? You may have a look `index` in mongodb

Comment: It does not seem efficient search multiple collections to get the results, you think it's good practice to use a collection to search only indexed text, the field would: name_business name_employee name_service, all concatenated. Then filter by position in all businesses found in the previous query.

Answer (score 0):

Your business model should be

```
    var BusinessSchema = new Schema({   
            business_id: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                unique:true
            },
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                type: String,
            },      
            description:{
                type: String
            },
            address:{
                country:{
                    type:String,
                },
                city:{
                    type:String
                }                
            },
            location : {
                type: [Number],
               index: '2dsphere'
            },       
            services:[{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Service'
            }],
            employees:[{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }]
        },
        {
            timestamps: true
        });
```

The change in schema is you have to create index on location, and for find business based on employee have to add employees id in business schema.Then you can you geo near query of mongodb.